# URI Scheme ms-word:nft|u| not working and not opening word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, uri, protocols

When using URI schemes to open a new document from from a word template hosted on a web page does not work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx

The issue just seems to be with my PC. I have tried others and it works fine.

I have office 365 Pro Plus and Visio Professional 2016 installed.

An example of a URI Scheme which opens a new document from a template is the link below.

[ms-word:nft|u|https://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/tf10067038.dotx](http://ms-word:nft%7Cu%7Chttps://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/tf10067038.dotx)

I have checked my registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-word which exists and looks right.

If I run the command below it works correctly

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\protocolhandler.exe "ms-word:nft|u|https://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/tf10067038.dotx"`

I have also changed key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-word\shell\open\command to

```
cmd /k echo %1
```

but this does not execute. But if I create a custom uri protocol handler like ms-wordTest then it will execute the shell command.

I now think that for Office products it does not use the uri protocol handler but something at the OS layer is taking control of uri's for office products.

No idea why it does not work on my PC but works on other PCs. Not sure where to look now.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a repair of Office 365 Pro Plus has fixed the issue

Comment: I have a related issue that causes the redirection to appear in the browser as expected but after clicking the "Open [app name]"  button, Office reports that "This action couldn't be performed because Office doesn't recognize the command it was given." Note that the Microsoft article referenced by Adrian was updated on 22nd Feb 2022.

Comment: We are issuing the same problem. We'd like to open files on a shared folder. We found out that on Office 2016 and 2019 Standard this protocol seem not to work, but with Office 2016 or Office 2019 PRO the call succeeds and opens the corresponding application (word, excel aso)
Does anybody know, whether this is restricted to PRO versions only?